# Обработка повторного нажатия и остановка mediaplayer

Tags: java, android

Как работает сейчас, нажимаю на R.id.b1 воспроизводится анимация, начинает играть мелодия, все что нужно, но необходимо сделать еще и так, что  бы если второй раз нажал на  R.id.b1 mediplayer остановился, а если 3-й раз нажал на R.id.b1 началось новое воспроизведение, а на деле, если я повторно нажимаю на R.id.b1 то песня просто начинает воспроизводится заново, но это из-за  mediaPlayer.reset();, но мне данный код необходим ,т.к он сбрасывает старую. мелодию если я воспроизвожу новую

```
 if (pageNumber == 1) {

              rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                    for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
                        arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                                    arr_imageB[index].clearAnimation();
                                     //очищаю анимацию
                                }


                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                    case R.id.b1: {
                                       //запуск анимации
                                        v.startAnimation(anim);
                                        /воспроизвожу мелодию
                                        playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);

                                    }
                                    break;
```

Код метода в котором пытаюсь сделать остановку плеера:
Сейчас так: выбрал R.id.b1: игарет мелодия, нажал еще раз R.id.b1: остановилась,нажал еще раз мелодия не запускается,а должна

```
private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        } else {

            try {
                //mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                afd.close();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в самом начале проверку

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    //надо остановить воспроизведение, т.к. сейчас оно проигрывается
} else {
   //делайте то, что сейчас - начинайте воспроизведение, т.к. сейчас плеер ничего не воспроизводит
}
```

Comment: не прошло такое,я уже пробовал

Comment: @upward, должно было *пройти*. Значит вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: обновил код метода,гляньте

Comment: @upward, раскомментируйте теперь строчку `mediaPlayer.reset();`

Comment: @ metalurgus
мелодия воспроизвод. нажимаю повторно и она снова воспроизводиться и т.д

Comment: Это похоже потому, что вы используете onTouchListener вместо OnClickLictener. onTouchListener получает при клике как минимум 2 события, поэтому сейчас мелодия сразу же воспроиводитя заново, какбудто вы 2 раза нажали.

Comment: @ metalurgus
спасибо,понял,буду разбираться,,все получилось

Comment: а как можно обработать данный баг?